# SuppressMessage in interface

Tags: fxcop, suppress-warnings

I tried to suppress a particular FxCop warning for a method defined in an interface by adding SuppressMessage attribute to the method. But the warning still appears. I know the SuppressMessage attribute is the right choice.

```
public interface ICustomerAccess
{
  [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design",
    "CA1024:UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate",
    Justification = "This method involves time-consuming operations", Scope="member")]
  IList<ICustomer> GetCustomers();
}
```

Does anyone have the experience on suppressing FxCop warning in an interface?

Thanks,

H

Comment: Here is the code. 

public interface ICustomerAccess 
{ 
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1024:UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate", Justification = "This method involves time-consuming operations", Scope="member")] 
IList<ICustomer> GetCustomers(); 

}

Comment: Did you define `CODE_ANALYSIS`?

Comment: Thank you very much! I am able to resolve the issue by adding CODE_ANALYSIS to the project.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the answer is in the question's comments:

> @Angelina said: Thank you very much! I
>   am able to resolve the issue by adding
>   CODE_ANALYSIS to the project.